# D3 Domain and Scale Bug

Tags: javascript, d3.js

(EDIT BECAUSE IT WAS TLDR NOV 18,2015 4:55 )

I am working with D3 I have two examples and the first is pretty perfect everything matches up nice and my domain and range are being respected perfectly

http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/ZbPvWG

When I go to add Dynamic Data by pulling in a JSON page my domain and range are no longer respected and my bars spread to the height of the container and beyond

```
      function Bar_Chart(graph_container, data_in, color){

  var t = this
  this.width = $(graph_container).width();
  this.height= $(graph_container).height();

  this.margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};

  this.color_scale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

  this.new_width = this.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  this.new_height = this.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

  //MIGHT BECOME DYNAMIC
  this.data = data_in;

  this.x_scale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, this.new_width],0.05);
  this.y_scale = d3.scale.linear().range([this.new_height, 0]);  

  this.x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(this.x_scale)
      .orient("bottom");

  this.y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(this.y_scale)
      .orient("left");

  this.svg = d3.select(graph_container).append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width )
      .attr("height", this.height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + t.margin.left + "," + t.margin.top + ")");

  this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x_axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.new_height + ")");

  this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y_axis");

  this.rects;

  d3.json(this.data, function(error, json) {

    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    t.data = json.slice(0,100);
    t.init()
});


}

Bar_Chart.prototype = {

  constructor:Bar_Chart,

  init:function(){

  console.log(this.data);
    this.consume_data(this.data);


  },
  consume_data(data_in){

    this.data = data_in;
    this.x_scale.domain(this.data.map(function(d,i) { return i}));
    this.y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function(d,i) { return d.employee_annual_salary ; })]);

    this.render_data()

  },


  render_data:function(){

    var t= this;
    var rect_width = this.new_width / this.data.length;

    render_axis();
    this.rects = this.svg.selectAll("rect").data(this.data); 

    this.rects.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x",  function(d,i){return rect_width*i } )
      .attr("y", this.new_height)
      .attr("width",   this.x_scale.rangeBand()  )
      .attr("height",0)
      .attr("fill", function(d){ return t.color_scale(d.department)  })

    this.rects
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x",  function(d,i){return rect_width*i } )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return  t.y_scale(d.employee_annual_salary)  })
      .attr("width",   this.x_scale.rangeBand()  )
      .attr("height", function(d,i){ return (t.new_height - t.y_scale(d.employee_annual_salary) )})


    this.rects.exit()
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .attr("y", this.new_height)
      .attr("height",0)
      .remove();


      function render_axis(){
        t.svg.select(".x_axis").transition().call(t.x_axis);
        t.svg.select(".y_axis").transition().call(t.y_axis);

      }

  },



}


var arr_one = [4564.54546546542, 8465.72454654654786,3459.9546546546444,7544.744654553,9457.18686,6546.246546559]
var arr_two = [945367.78673,456456457.7867756453,9956456.75699,646456.78678678]
var color_one = "rebeccapurple";
var color_two = "blue";


var b_chart = new Bar_Chart("#chart", "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.json");
var clicked = false;
/*
$('body').on("click", function(){
  if(clicked){
     b_chart.consume_data(arr_one);  
    clicked = false;
  }else{
     b_chart.consume_data(arr_two);  
    clicked = true;
  }

})
```

http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/yYwpVy?editors=101

What is causing the dynamic data to spread beyond the boundaries I have set?

Comment: Could you narrow it down to a minimal example please? It's difficult to see what's going on in the full example.

Comment: Took out the first code snippet that was working perfect but left the example link. Code showing is for the dynamic example that is not showing correct behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `employee_annual_salary` field is a string, not a number, and therefore finding the maximum value does not work as you'd expect. To fix this, replace line 71 with this:

```
this.y_scale.domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function(d,i) { return +d.employee_annual_salary ; })]);
```

The difference is the `+` which, by JavaScript's idea of a sensible operation, converts the value after it to a number. Alternatively, do this when you load the data.

Comment: this did the trick perfectly. You can see the resutls here. 

http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/yYwpVy?editors=101

If you are in Chicago or find yourself in Chicago lemme buy you a beer.